# Merge dataframes based on column values with duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes based on equal column values. The problem is that one of my columns have duplicated row values, which cannot be drop since it's correlated to another columns. Here's an example of my two dataframes:

[image: DF1]
[image: DF2]

Essentialy, I want to merge this two dataframes based on equal values of **FromPatchID** (df1) and **Id** (df2) columns, in order to get something like this:

```
FromPatchID    ToPatchID    ...    Id     MMM     LB
    1              1        ...    1     26.67   27.67
    1              2        ...    1     26.67   27.67
    1              3        ...    1     26.67   27.67
    2              1        ...    2     26.50   27.50
    3              1        ...    3     26.63   27.63
```

I already tried a simple merge with `df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['FromPatchID','Id'])`, but I got KeyError indicating to *check for duplicates* in FromPatchID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the different column names to match on with `left_on` and `right_on`. Also specify `how='right'` to use only keys from the right frame.

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='FromPatchID', right_on='Id', how='right')
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! The only point is that I had to specify how='left' instead of 'right' to merge within the whole range of my df1 :)